# Unreadable files

Tags: android, filesystems

I have a strange problem with files in app directory. 
I unzip downloaded file in specific directory, for example 
`/data/data/my.package/files/3.0/`
and some of files has numbers as file name, for example `763.jpg`. 
And those files are unreadable for my application.

Any ideas why?﻿

Comment: What do you mean with 'unreadable' ? InputStream read() fails()?

Comment: file.exists() return false, but in file structure this file exists (and path in File object is correct).

Comment: Unzip them to external memory so you can investigate with other apps and viewers.

Comment: I've found a bug - it was server fault - after generating graphic files there was a space after file extension - "736.jpg "